# Remove duplicate values from python dictionary value for the same key

Tags: pyhook

I have a python dictionary

```
graph = {'A': ['B', 'C','B'], 'E': ['C', 'D']}
```

I would like to remove the duplicate values from my dictionary & would like to have in this form

```
graph = {'A': ['B', 'C'], 'E': ['C', 'D']}
```

This is the sample dataset. I'm not sure for how many cases it's occurring.
Can you suggest me how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is to convert list into set and then back into list.

```
graph = {'A': ['B', 'C','B'], 'E': ['C', 'D']}
for idx, k in enumerate(graph):
    graph[k] = list(set(graph[k]))
print(graph)
```